# How to use an "if" statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Im trying to insert an "if" statement in this code but Its not working to well.  Its a fixed salary and an incentive(37.28 * 1.32) will be give once 94,261.02 is made.  Making less than 94,261.02 is just a regular 37.28 commission.  All iny "int" lines are underlined in red with red ! marks. So I'm trying to figure the problem:

```
        System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");
        String annual = input.nextLine();

        int salary = 7550281; 
        int commission = 38_28; 
        int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
        System.out.println("compensation is: "+compensation );

        if (Integer.parseInt(annual) < 92416_02) {
          int salary = 7550281;
          int commission = 37_28 * 1_32;
          int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
          System.out.println("compensation is: "+compensation );

        } else if (Integer.parseInt(annual) > 92416_02){
         int salary = 7550281; 
         int commission = 38_28; 
         int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
         System.out.println("compensation is: "+compensation );
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Java 1.7 allows _ in numeric values, for better presentation/readability.

Comment: Numbers that use `_` have not been supported since compiler version `1.6`, we are now on like `7`...

Comment: @Batty Seriously?  That makes for better presentation :P

Comment: yes, if you have number like 1000000000000, its better to use 1_000_000_000_000.

Comment: @Batty Guess I'm just use to using smaller numbers ;) - Nice to know though...

Comment: @Batty nice information...

Answer (score 2):

A lot will come down to which version of Java you are using.

For the moment, let's assume you are using Java 7 and `38_28` is a valid statement, you are redeclaring your variables within each `if` block

```
// Declared here...
int salary = 7550281;
int commission = 38_28;
int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
if (Integer.parseInt(annual) < 92416_02) {
    // Redeclared here...
    int salary = 7550281;
    int commission = 37_28 * 1_32;
    int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
} else if (Integer.parseInt(annual) > 92416_02) {
    // Redeclared here...
    int salary = 7550281;
    int commission = 38_28;
    int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
}
```

This is not required.  You only need to declare them once, for example...

```
int salary = 7550281;
int commission = 38_28;
int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
if (Integer.parseInt(annual) < 92416_02) {
    salary = 7550281;
    commission = 37_28 * 1_32;
    compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
} else if (Integer.parseInt(annual) > 92416_02) {
    salary = 7550281;
    commission = 38_28;
    compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
}
```

I think you'll also be safer using `long` over `int` to prevent any possible overflow

**Nit Pick**

You are also, repeatedly, converting the `annual` value.  While there is little wrong with it, it does tend to clutter the code and makes it a little difficult to read.  It would suggest converting it once and simply re-using the resulting value, for example...

```
int annualAmount = Integer.parseInt(annual);
if (annualAmount < 92416_02) {
    //...
    compensation = annualAmount * commission + salary;
} else if (annualAmount > 92416_02) {
    //...
    compensation = annualAmount * commission + salary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use floats and `.` instead of `_`, eg : `float commission = 38.28;`

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code , since you didn't provide complete code block , I did the code segment by my imagination. I would recommend you to use BigDecimal class for more precise calculation.
'

```
import java.util.Scanner;        
public class stack_overflow {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String annual = input.nextLine();
        double salary = 7550281; 
        double commission = 38.28; 
        double compensation = Double.parseDouble(annual) * commission + salary;
        System.out.println("compensation is: "+compensation );

        if (Double.parseDouble(annual) < 92416.02) {
           salary = 7550281;
           commission = 37.28 * 1.32;
           compensation = Double.parseDouble(annual) * commission + salary;
           System.out.println("compensation is: "+compensation );

        } else if (Integer.parseInt(annual) > 92416.02){
          salary = 7550281; 
          commission = 38.28; 
          compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission + salary;
          System.out.println("compensation is: "+compensation );
    }
}
```

Comment: changing it to double could help but it messes up my code when I cange it.  my int compensation line becomes underlined in red

Answer (score 0):

Your code suffers from the following problems:

1. Local variables duplication (salary, compensation and commission are declared twice). If you want to assign value to already existing variable, you shouldn't specify a type (`int` here) before the variable name.
2. Your multiplication is invalid. `37_28 * 1_32` gives `492096`. Underscores don't matter at all. You probably have to divide your result by 100 to give it logical sence.
3. Your code doesn't handle the case when the annual is exactly 92416_02. Remove the `else if` clause and initialize your `commission` instead, or just use `else` without following `if`. Also, since there are so many lines common, you could just move them out of if block.

Note also that the user has to input their annual multiplied by 100 since parseInt won't recognize underscores. Otherwise, this code can probably do what you want:
    System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");
    String annual = input.nextLine();

```
    int salary = 7550281;
    int commission = 38_28;
    if (Integer.parseInt(annual) < 92416_02) {
      commission = 37_28 * 1_32 / 100;
    }
    int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission / 100 + salary;
    System.out.println("compensation is: "+compensation );
```

P.S. Don't listen to people suggesting floats or doubles for calculations with money - this is a bad, error-prone practice because calculation errors accumulate over time. Use int, long, BigInteger or BigDecimal (with String constructor)

Comment: hmmm, I like how with this I didnt need to use an else statement with the commission. Thanks.  it ran but complied with this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable salary is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
 at commission.main(commission.java:24)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @MoMarks, that's because _variable salary is already defined_. Look trough your whole source, this snippet compiles without a problem.